# Attempted import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

***Me sale este problema al importar el router-dom, algo extraño ya que anteriormente haciendo otros proyectos no tengo ningun problema***

**Attempted import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.**

```
 esta es la version que tengo instalada **"react-router-dom": "^6.0.0",**


import "./App.css";
import Formulario from "./components/Formulario";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Layout>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Formulario} />
          </Switch>
        </Layout>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Hay que verificar que no se esta tratando de importar `switch` desde otro componente (otro archivo).

Comment: Tuve problemas con la app que estaba haciendo y no podia solucionarlo. Cree una nueva y me pasa lo mismo, en anteriores apps no tuve un solo problema, no se que sera

Comment: Parece que hubo un reemplazo en la version 6, [Switch es ahora Routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#upgrade-all-switch-elements-to-routes); `In order to use v6, you'll need to convert all your <Switch> elements to <Routes>`

Comment: Sigue el error, por mas que cambie por <Routes> no renderea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

en la version 6 cambio la sintaxis ahora es asi

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
// import your route components too

render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="teams" element={<Teams />}>
          <Route path=":teamId" element={<Team />} />
          <Route path="new" element={<NewTeamForm />} />
          <Route index element={<LeagueStandings />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

En react-router-dom v5 hubiera funcionado el componente switch pero ya en la versión 6 no funciona y tenes que remplazarlo por

```javascript
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
const App = () => {
   return (
      <BrowserRouter>
         <Routes>       
           <Route path="/main" element={<ForecastChart data={data}/>} />    
         </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
   )
}
```

Fijate que el componente está expresado así:

```
element={ <Component /> }
```

Y no así:

```
element={Component}
```

Comment: Reemplazar <switch> por <routes>

Diferencia entre v5 y v6 en su página: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#upgrade-all-switch-elements-to-routes

Comment: Yo digo, porqué no dejan de votar en contra y dan su opinión o una mejor solución

Answer (score 0):

intenta de esta manera , de igual manera ya no se recomienda utilizar classes

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Layout>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Formulario} />
          </Switch>
        </Layout>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

puedes guiarte de la [documentacion](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) , en donde se utiliza `function`